# Difference between Switch-Disconnector and Disconnecting Switch?

Tags: switches

I'm an electrical engineering student doing an intership at the moment and I was hoping that some of you might be able to help me out with some things I'm having trouble with:

Is a switch- disconnector just another name for a disconnect switch?

Are these circuit elements operated manually (by hand)?

If regular switching is required in the circuit, will it be necessary to also incorporate contactors in series?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last question. Could you please expand upon it?

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't heard of a "switch-disconnector" before. But googling that takes you right to ABB's disconnect switches. So I'd say the two are synonymous. I've also heard them called isolators or isolation switches.

They are usually operated by hand and used to ensure that a system or circuit is completely de-energized before maintenance is performed on it.